# Add Pod to a kubernetes Job created by a CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, jobs, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a CronJob which is defined to forbid concurrency (`concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`). Now the Pod which is launched by the Job by the CronJob itself spawns a Pod (which is out of my control) which in turn also may or may not spawn a Pod.

```
··········> ··········> time ··········> ··········>

CronJob
    |
    +-----------------------+----····
    |                       |
  schedules               schedules
    |                       |
    v                       v
first Pod ~~~> Exit.    first Pod ~~~> Exit.
    |                       |
  spawns                  spawns
    |                       |
    |                        SECOND COMING OF SECOND POD CONCURRENT WITH FIRST
    v                       
second Pod ~~~~~~ still running ~~~~~~>
```

Now the first Pod exits fairly quickly leaving the CronJob controller under the impression that the Job is done. But the job is actually still running, as it spawned a Pod. So the next time the Job is scheduled by the CronJob it may spawn a Pod which runs concurrently to the other Pods spawned by the first scheduled Job. Which is exactly what I am trying to prevent.

Is there a way that my first pod (I have full control over the first pod, except of the fact that it spawns a pod and I do not control what's going on in that pod or how it is spawned, but I can set labels and annotations) somehow adds the consecutively spawned pods to the current Job such that it only is deemed finished once these pods return?

---

My current approach is that I am checking for these spawned pods myself, but it's quite tedious and I'd prefer if there was a solution in kubernetes already. Also it would simply my infrastructure as the garbage collector which cleans the job remains would then also clean up these pods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid **kubernetes** won't be able to handle it for you. I would say its rather about the application logic. Kubernetes `Pod` is not aware in any way that it spawned a different `Pod` or that such `Pod` was spawned by it.

The second `Pod` is spawned by your app running in the first `Pod` and this app is reaponsible for handling this process. It may watch such `Pods` and exit only when all of such sub-`Pods` are terminated. You can compare it with process management on the OS, where the perant process typically doesn't exit before terminating its child processes.

You may also think about implementing [container lifecycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) so that your parent `Pods` get notified e.g. when a child `Pod` finishes its job and terminates.

Comment: As I say in. my question, my current approach is to watch for these pods myself. I am wondering though whether I can patch the job resource to also take into account the pods I spawned such that I do not have to do it myself.

Comment: When you say "Kubernetes Pod is not aware in any way that it spawned a different Pod" do you mean "Kubernetes _Job_ is not aware..."?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Does the fact that I did not accept the question as the answer answer your question?